# Value not passing to directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The isHidden value is not getting through to my Directive, so my animation isn't working.

I've console.logged everything and it seems to be failing at the `attrs`.

I'm using angular 1.2.

I'm sure it's a simple bug I just can't see it.

```
// Homepage Controller
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $route, $location) {

   isHidden = false;

   console.log(isHidden);

   $scope.fadeIt = function(){
        isHidden = !isHidden;
        console.log("clicked");
        console.log(isHidden);
   }    
});

// Directive
app.directive("hideMe", function($animate){
    return function (scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.hideMe, function(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
            if (newVal) {
                $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
            } else {
                $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");  
            }
        })
    }
});

// Animation
app.animation('.fade', function() {
  return { 
    addClass: function(element, className) {    
                TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {opacity:0});
       },
    removeClass: function(element, className) {    
                TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {opacity:1});
       }   
     }
});
```

Template

```
<a ng-click="fadeIt()">fade</a> 
<div hide-me="app.isHidden">test</div>
```

Comment: you cannot use '-' sign as in `attrs.hide-me`. You need to change it to `attrs.hideMe`. See my answer below.

Comment: I've edited the directive above to show what i'm testing now.

Comment: could you put in more of your html? I think the current problem isn't about the directive you might have a problem with how you reference isHidden.

Comment: that is all thats in my html, could it be because I'm using ngView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm sure its a simple bug I just can't see it.

First off, I would change directive name to `hideMe` instead `hide-me`:

```
app.directive("hideMe", function($animate) 
  //....
```

when in HTML leave it the same: `<div hide-me="isHidden">test</div>`

The other thing, you can write HTML directive like:

```
<div hide-me hide="isHidden">test</div>
```

*controller*

```
$scope.isHidden = false;
```

and directive:

```
// Directive
app.directive("hideMe", function($animate){
    return function (scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.hide, function(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
            if (newVal) {
                $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
            } else {
                $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");  
            }
        }, true)// <- deep watch might help too
    }
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/874/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You should change the directive name from hide-me to hideMe as well as changing the `$scope.watch` statement to use the camelCase version. The following directive should work.

```
app.directive("hideMe", function($animate){
    var link = function (scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.hideMe, function(newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $animate.addClass(element, "fade");
            } else {
                $animate.removeClass(element, "fade");  
            }
        })
    }
    return {
         link:link
    };
});
```

you might want to change the way you reference isHidden in the html and your controller. Try something like this,

```
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <a ng-click="fadeIt()">fade</a> 
    <div hide-me="isHidden">test</div>
</div>
```

also change `isHidden = false;` kind of usage in your controller to `$scope.isHidden = false;`.

Comment: The console log for newVal is still coming back as undefined

Comment: try returning your main directive function as a link function. I've edited the answer to show how.